# Catching divs on top of each other during drag and drop operation with html drag drop

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, draggable

I'm building a drag drop application with React. I used html drag drop. My div elements are draggable. I want to make the background of the target div yellow when dragging and dropping another div onto a div.

I kept these divs in a state called blocks and tried to capture them according to their positions, but without success.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.